# Error while configuring LDAP on JBOSS EAP

Tags: jboss, ldap

I need to configure ldap in jboss eap so that when user will able to access the application URL in case it exists in my AD.

**Environment Details** JBoss EAP 6.2, client station with Windows 7 64bit + Chrome Windows, Server 2008 Active Directory

**Configuration Done in Standalone.xml**

```
<security-domain name="my_ldap_security_domain">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="LdapExtended" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                        <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://AD IP:389"/>
                        <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                        <module-option name="bindDN" value="CN=siddharth,DC=eco,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="bindCredential" value="secret"/>
                        <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="DC=eco,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="CN=sso,DC=eco,DC=com"/>
                        <module-option name="roleFilter" value="(member={1})"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                        <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="searchScope" value="SUBTREE_SCOPE"/>
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

**Error in Server Logs**

10:21:32,455 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
10:21:32,459 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000200: Begin isValid, principal: siddharth, cache entry: null
10:21:32,460 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000209: defaultLogin, principal: siddharth
10:21:32,460 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000221: Begin getAppConfigurationEntry(other), size: 3
10:21:32,460 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000222: getAppConfigurationEntry(other), no entry found, trying parent config null
10:21:32,460 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000223: getAppConfigurationEntry(other), no entry in parent config, trying default other
10:21:32,461 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000225: End getAppConfigurationEntry(other), failed to find entry
10:21:32,461 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000221: Begin getAppConfigurationEntry(other), size: 3
10:21:32,461 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000222: getAppConfigurationEntry(other), no entry found, trying parent config null
10:21:32,462 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000223: getAppConfigurationEntry(other), no entry in parent config, trying default other
10:21:32,462 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000225: End getAppConfigurationEntry(other), failed to find entry
10:21:32,463 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for other
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.SubjectActions$LoginContextAction.run(SubjectActions.java:179) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.SubjectActions$LoginContextAction.run(SubjectActions.java:162) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.SubjectActions.createLoginContext(SubjectActions.java:332) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:407) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:216) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:178) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

10:21:32,465 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000201: End isValid, result = false
10:21:32,466 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
10:21:37,310 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000200: Begin isValid, principal: siddharth, cache entry: null
10:21:37,310 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000209: defaultLogin, principal: siddharth
10:21:37,311 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000221: Begin getAppConfigurationEntry(other), size: 3
10:21:37,311 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000222: getAppConfigurationEntry(other), no entry found, trying parent config null
10:21:37,311 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000223: getAppConfigurationEntry(other), no entry in parent config, trying default other
10:21:37,312 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000225: End getAppConfigurationEntry(other), failed to find entry
10:21:37,312 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000221: Begin getAppConfigurationEntry(other), size: 3
10:21:37,312 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000222: getAppConfigurationEntry(other), no entry found, trying parent config null
10:21:37,312 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000223: getAppConfigurationEntry(other), no entry in parent config, trying default other
10:21:37,313 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000225: End getAppConfigurationEntry(other), failed to find entry
10:21:37,313 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for other
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.SubjectActions$LoginContextAction.run(SubjectActions.java:179) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.SubjectActions$LoginContextAction.run(SubjectActions.java:162) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.SubjectActions.createLoginContext(SubjectActions.java:332) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:407) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1.jar:4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:216) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthenticator.java:178) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:465) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]

10:21:37,322 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000201: End isValid, result = false
10:21:37,323 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-2) PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null

Kindly help me in order to resolve the same.

Comment: Is your application correctly referencing the security domain? It rather seems it uses the default one named "other".

Comment: I have configured the same in jboss-web.xml in my application war.<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/my_ldap_security_domain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>